# Python - Dictionary - Modify __getitem__?

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok so i've build my own variable handler which has a `__getitem__` function for use when accessing data via data[key], it works great except for when trying to access a link of items:

```
data["key"]["subkey"]


def __getitem__(self, key, **args):
    print key
    ...
    return self.dict[key]
```

When trying to access a subkey that doesn't exist, Python simply returns a KeyError without printing "subkey", why is this and how can I get Python to print out what I'm actually trying to get?

I know that I've probably misunderstood the mechanics but is there a way to emulate a dictionary AND follow the string of data that's being requested?
Mainly so I can dynamically log the missing variables in a dictionary flow...

This obviously works (but it's not the native syntax that I like):

```
data["key:subkey"]

def __getitem__(self, key, **args):
    for slice in key.split(':'):
        print key
    ...
```

The goal is to emulate the following,

Works:

```
data = {'key' : {'subkey' : 1}}
print data["key"]["subkey"]
```

Will not work, but I want to catch the exception within `__getitem__` and then create the missing key automatically or just log the missing subkey:

```
data = {'key' : {}}
print data["key"]["subkey"]
```

---

## Solution:

```
class Var():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {'test' : {}}
    def __getitem__(self, var, **args):
        print ':',var
        if var in self.dict:
            v = Var(self.dict[var])
            return v

print vHandle['test']['down']
```

Output:

> : test
>
> : down
>
> None

Comment: Am I missing something here, or did this not deserve a downvote at all? Could the downvoter explain themselves?

Comment: What is the type of `data`?  What is the type of `data["key"]`?  You probably need to show more code -- otherwise all we can do is guess.  (Not my downvote)

Comment: No, you can't do it directly (you can by returning a wrapped object doing the same thigns). Think of it this way: `_ = data['key']` followed by `_['subkey']`. You could alternatively have `data['key', 'subkey']` (tuple keys) if that was a valid way of accessing the data.

Comment: Ok so there's no way to emulate/replace the excisting dictionary way of accessing data without toubles, list or split()?

Comment: @Torxed: you can have `data['key', 'subkey]` and it will call `__getitem__` with `key == ('key', 'subkey')`. That's neater than using a string and splitting on colon. But if you return a wrapped object with `__getitem__` defined, it can be done. I'd prefer the tuple-keys version if it were feasible for your use case (it may or may not be)

Comment: Formatting note: you can get magic method names (leading and trailing underscores) to be formatted correctly by putting them in code with the backtick (preferred), or by prefixing the first underscore with a backslash to escape it.

Comment: Heh, thx Chris! I'm still a bit new here and trying to learn the formats.

My accepted answer works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact is that when Python encounters an expression such as `data["key"]["subkey"]`, what is done internally is `(data["key"])["subkey"]`. That is, the first part of the expression is resolved: the retrievalof the item "key" from the object "data". Then, Python tries do call `__getitem__` on the resulting object of that expression. 
If such resulting object does not have a `__getitem__`method itself, there is your error.

There are two possible workarounds there: you should either work with "tuple indexes" - like
`data["key", "subkey"]`(and then test on your `__getitem__` method wether you got a tuple instance as the key) - or make `__getitem__` return an specialized object that also features a `__getitem__` method - even if all it does is to log the requested keys.

Comment: So that's how it works, i just assumed that python would automaticly call __getitem__ through the same variable instance again after the first key, i'm guessing i have to return a second instance of my variable handle so that __getitem__ exists for the second call.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Remember: `tmp = foo['bar']['baz']` is the same as `tmp = foo['bar']; tmp = tmp['baz']`

So to allow arbitrary depths your `__getitem__` method must return a new object that also contains such a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: i'm guessing i have to return a second instance of my variable handle from within the "variable handler" so that __getitem__ exists for the second call as well then.

Thank you!