# Chained, nested dict() get calls in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm interrogating a nested dictionary using the dict.get('keyword') method.  Currently my syntax is...

```
M = cursor_object_results_of_db_query

for m in M:
    X = m.get("gparents").get("parent").get("child")
    for x in X:
        y = x.get("key")
```

However, sometimes one of the "parent" or "child" tags doesn't exist, and my script fails.  I know using `get()` I can include a default in the case the key doesn't exist of the form...

```
get("parent", '') or
get("parent", 'orphan')
```

But if I include any `Null`, `''`, or empty I can think of, the chained `.get("child")` fails when called on `''.get("child")` since `""` has no method `.get()`.

The way I'm solving this now is by using a bunch of sequential `try-except` around each `.get("")` call, but that seems foolish and unpython---is there a way to default return `"skip"` or `"pass"` or something that would still support chaining and fail intelligently, rather than deep-dive into keys that don't exist?

Ideally, I'd like this to be a list comprehension of the form:

```
[m.get("gparents").get("parent").get("child") for m in M]
```

but this is currently impossible when an absent parent causes the `.get("child")` call to terminate my program.

Comment: I don't see anything `requests` specific here. Are you talking about the JSON responses? Those are plain python dictionaries, and their use is separate from the `requests` library.

Comment: I hadn't realized that was plain python dict().  Apologies, updating.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378380/python-dictionary-modify-getitem

Comment: **See also (python dpath):** https://stackexchange.com/search?q=dpath%20python and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508328/42223

Comment: Are you asking about a type of null-coalescing operator for Python (C# comes to mind: https://kodify.net/csharp/operators/null-coalescing-operator/)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Since these are all python `dict`s and you are calling the `dict.get()` method on them, you can use an empty `dict` to chain:

```
[m.get("gparents", {}).get("parent", {}).get("child") for m in M]
```

By leaving off the default for the last `.get()` you fall back to `None`. Now, if any of the intermediary keys is not found, the rest of the chain will use empty dictionaries to look things up, terminating in `.get('child')` returning `None`.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is to recognize that if the key isn't found, `dict.get` returns `None`.  However, `None` doesn't have an attribute `.get`, so it will throw an `AttributeError`:

```
for m in M:
    try:
       X = m.get("gparents").get("parent").get("child")
    except AttributeError:
       continue

    for x in X:
        y = x.get("key")
        #do something with `y` probably???
```

Just like Martijn's answer, this doesn't guarantee that `X` is iterable (non-`None`).  Although, you could fix that by making the last `get` in the chain default to returning an empty list:

```
 try:
    X = m.get("gparents").get("parent").get("child",[])
 except AttributeError:
    continue
```

---

Finally, I think that probably the best solution to this problem is to use `reduce`:

```
try:
    X = reduce(dict.__getitem__,["gparents","parent","child"],m)
except (KeyError,TypeError):
    pass
else:
    for x in X:
       #do something with x
```

The advantage here is that you know if any of the `get`s failed based on the type of exception that was raised.  It's possible that a `get` returns the wrong type, then you get a `TypeError`.  If the dictionary doesn't have the key however, it raises a `KeyError`.  You can handle those separately or together.  Whatever works best for your use case.

Comment: Oooh, I see what you did there. You got to use your `reduce()` sans `lambda` there! :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I've just been itching to use it ever since I cooked it up the other day ;-).

Answer (score 6):

How about using a small helper function?

```
def getn(d, path):
    for p in path:
        if p not in d:
            return None
        d = d[p]
    return d
```

and then

```
[getn(m, ["gparents", "parent", "child"]) for m in M]
```

Answer (score 6):

I realise I'm a bit late for the part but here's the solution I came up with when faced with a similar problem:

```
def get_nested(dict_, *keys, default=None):
    if not isinstance(dict_, dict):
        return default
    elem = dict_.get(keys[0], default)
    if len(keys) == 1:
        return elem
    return get_nested(elem, *keys[1:], default=default)
```

For example:

```
In [29]: a = {'b': {'c': 1}}
In [30]: get_nested(a, 'b', 'c')
Out[30]: 1
In [31]: get_nested(a, 'b', 'd') is None
Out[31]: True
```

Comment: BTW, this `def get_nested(dict_, *keys, default=None)` only works in python 3 (the keyword `default` arg after the `*keys`